# Kivy Change Z-index

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm still getting the hang of both kivy and python so bear with me. I have two layouts, my Graph layout is overriding the properties of my TopBar layout. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is my .kv file:

```
Root:
    orientation: "vertical"

    TopBar:
        size_hint: 1,0.08
        size_hint_max_y: 100
        pos_hint: {"top":1}

        TextInput:
            text: "Search"
            right: True
            size_hint_max_x: 200
        Button:
            text: str(self.state)
    Graph:
        size_hint_max_y: 100
        Button:
            text: "test"
```

Here's the python file:

```
class Root(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class TopBar(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Graph(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Gui(App):
    def build(self):
       return Root()

Gui().run()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## kv file

Move `size_hint_max_y: 100` from under `Graph:` to under `Button:`.

In the snippet, color was added to illustrates the *Graph*'s canvas.

### Snippet

```
Graph:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.5    # 50% blue
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Button:
        size_hint_max_y: 100
        text: "test"
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Thanks didn't realize that earlier, but is there a way to resize the actual layout?

Comment: To resize the Graph layout, for example: use `size_hint: 1, None` and `size_hint_y: 0.5`